# Bootstrap в группу ввода добавить иконку

Tags: html, bootstrap

Привет) помогите пж!!

Хочу в строку ввода добавить иконку глазика-кнопочки чтобы тип ввода менялся на текст с пароля, и наоборот. Открыла доки бутстрапа, скопипастила, и ничего не работает((( Подскажите, как можно все поправить?

P.s. bootstrap.min.css подключен

```
<label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" id="password">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="watch()">
                <span id="eye" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
//another code

<script>
    function watch () {
        let elem = document.getElementById('password');
        if (elem.type === 'password') {
            elem.type = 'text';
        } else {
            elem.type = 'password';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Получается вот что: (кривовато)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сдается мне подключен у вас бутстрап 4, а доки читаете к бутстрап 3

Comment: бутстрап построен с использавонием jquery. вот и пишите с использованием библиотеки этой. не надо в html вставлять всякие `onclick` и юзать `getElementById`. получается у вас мешанина из всего. Пишите с использованием библиотеки

Comment: https://codepen.io/Qanser/pen/dVRGJv

Comment: @entithat что-то js код у вас там чрезмерно раздут одно банальное `.toggleClass()` сократит его вдвое

Comment: @teran, та это не мой. Первая ссылка в гугле :)